# feasibility of git without a remote repo

Tags: git

So it seems to me like the most basic of git operations could be done effectively without a remote. ie. You could add and you could commit without a problem.

It seems like the biggest problem with a git repo without a remote would be stuff like `git reset`. Like if you want to revert your code to a particular commit twenty commits ago - just to test to see if something worked back then or something - it doesn't seem like you could do it. You do `git reset --hard ...` and then you've lost your twenty newest commits and there's no way to get them back.

What else wouldn't work?

Comment: Everything you can do with git you can do locally. Of course, if you delete your work without having a backup (e.g. a remote copy), well you have deleted stuff!! (Which is actually recoverable if you know the id). Like the answers say, you don't usually do `git reset --hard ...` just to move back to a commit, you create a branch.

Comment: Git is distributed. That means you have the entire repo. A remote is nothing more than another repo that your repo knows about. Usually it's another copy of your repo, but it can even be a completely different repo. Every bit of history is in your local copy, so you can checkout or reset whenever you like to any of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to avoid the problem you're concerned about.

You can be pro-active, as @mamapitufo suggests, and create a branch before you do anything like `git reset --hard`.  This is fine, as long as you remember to do it regularly.

If you're less than clairvoyant, use `git reflog` after you realize you've lost some commits you want.  `git` retains unreachable commits, that is, those that can't be found from any branch tip, in the repository for 30 days. `git reflog branch-name` shows all the recent changes to the head of the named branch, and from that you can use `git reset --hard` again to get back to where your were.

You can use `git checkout sha1` to move around in the history *without* changing your branch tips.  When you're done exploring, use `git checkout branchname` to get back in sync with a branch head.

Finally, if all else fails, you can use `git fsck` to look for dangling commits.  If `git fsck` can't find the commit you want, only then has it probably been purged from the repository.

By the way, a remote repository can be another one on the same machine, so you can still use git's remote repo features even without a network.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a branch that points to the specific commit you want and switch to it:

```
git checkout -b test-branch <commit-id>
```

When you are done with it you can get rid of the branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d test-branch
```

Comment: Note that `git checkout <commit-id>` is fine as well, as long as you don't try to commit anything (this is the so-called detached head).

Comment: @chepner - is `git checkout <commit-id>` an overall better way to do things even when you do have a remote? I think the biggest worry for me would be that since I currently use `get reset` to do that I might forget to create a branch out of carelessness. I mean, creating a branch for this purpose would definitely work but it seems like it'd be an easy process to skip if you weren't already in the practice of doing that.

Comment: I think the only need for a remote is as a backup, or as a central location for multiple contributors to push changes. I would save `git reset` for the (rare?) instances where you want to make a permanent change to the commit which a branch head points to.

Comment: the only reason I'd use a reset is if I want to make permanent changes to my commits or working directory. If you just want to jump temporarily to a specific snapshot of your source history, use checkout (either to a branch or just to a given commit).

Answer (score 1):

I never reset for testing, just checkout to that commit, yea you will be on a detached head mode but who cares, you are only testing, if you decide you want to reset then then do it. I always do this

```
git checkout HEAD~
```

which means go back 1 commit from current head, when I'm done I can simply checkout back to the branch name because it's still pointing to the original commit

```
git checkout master # or any other branch
```

and to create a new branch from the current commit you can do

```
git branch some-new-name
```

if you need to create a new branch and `checkout` to it you can do `checkout -b` like @mamapitufo suggested, but no need for commit id, by default it takes current HEAD as the new branch.

As a side note, even if you don't want to create a remote, it's useful to have another backup somewhere else, which is "the remote", the remote could be another folder in the same hard disk, or a network folder, or a network pc, just think of not like not keeping all your eggs in one basket.

**PS:** Actually `git reset` would work, because git by default doesn't remove any thing right away, if you really really want to reset, if you still have the old commit hash you can reset back by doing `git reset <hash>` and there you are back.

But keep in mind that doesn't include uncommitted files nor untracked files.